# Does Yahoo Calendar API (CalDav) works with OAuth?

Tags: oauth, calendar, yahoo, caldav

Does Yahoo Calendar API (CalDav) works with OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

It's been in private testing for close to two years now. Unfortunately there is no public documentation for it and no official announcement when or if it will be released.

Source: http://lists.calconnect.org/pipermail/caldeveloper-l/2015-January/000805.html

Comment: i can connect to yahoo using php from my  local server, but not in aws server

Answer (score 0):

Since the huge Yahoo hack, they blocked access to calendar (and email) via OAuth. You have to use basic authentication.